# Android JDBC : Some issues with using MySql JDBC in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am using Eclipse in Windows and i want to connect to a MySql DB.
I know i should use JDBC. But i don't know how to use it!

I have downloaded both msi and zip file from [JDBC download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

**In the zip file, a file with this name exsits : mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar
What should i do with this?**

*I mean where i copy/import (in a folder or in eclipse) this file*?

Note that i have this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LearningActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://cool/app";
    private static final String user = "user";
    private static final String pass = "password";

    private Button button;
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Connect();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Connect() {
        Connect task = new Connect();
        task.execute();
    }

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass); 

                String result = "Database connection success\n";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
                }
                tv.setText(result);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tv.setText(e.toString());
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error : ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Do you use a system like maven / ant to compile or is this a standalone project ?

Comment: @DeepakBala : No, this is a standalone project. I run that with AVD.

Comment: AVD ? This is an android project ? Do you see a folder called `libs` inside your android project ? Have you placed the jar there ?

Comment: yes bro. this is an android app. :)
Let me to check it exist or not...

Comment: No. there is no folder like **libs**. Only these folders exist : src, gen, res and assets

Comment: I suspect you are using an old version of ADT that creates android projects without that folder. The [folder hierarchy](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) should include a libs folder. Create one and put your jar there. Ensure that it is part of the build path for your application and then launch it into the device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50967/discussion-between-ali-bagheri-shakib-and-deepak-bala)

Comment: It's totally beyond me why we frequently see questions about accessing server-side databases directly from Android apps. Folks, they're different tiers. Client-Server design like this died in 1980s. Has anyone heard the terms "API" or "HTTP" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An offline discussion with @Ali revealed that he was using an old version of the ADT that does not create the `libs` folder as shown in the folder hierarchy on the [android developers web site](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Manually creating this folder solved the problem for him.

Note: The name of the folder is libs with a "**s**" at the end. It is easy to miss that and create `lib` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I place these in a lib directory inside my eclipse project, then add the jar to my build path.

Comment: I do my JDBC connection through Spring, so, I can't help you further.

Comment: The problem solved my friend. :) I add a folder **libs** and copy jar file into it, then add it to JavaBuildPath.